# WPF DataGrid shows length instead of path

Tags: c#, wpf, directory

I tried below code to retrieve directory name but it shows Length?

```
List<string> merchants = new List<string>();
foreach (string i in Directory.GetDirectories(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "/Data/").ToList())
{
   merchants.Add(i);
}
merchantTable.ItemsSource = merchants;
```

result is

```
|Length|
_______________________
|20    |
|29    |
```

i tried below answers but same problem

[How to get Directories name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26364708/how-to-get-directories-name)

[Getting the folder name from a path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3736462/getting-the-folder-name-from-a-path)

**WPF Code**

```
<DataGrid x:Name="merchantTable" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="15,39,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="208" Height="343"/>
```

**Update**

i use MessageBox it shows 
Returned values are Full path like `C:\.....\Data\.....`

Comment: The code works fine - it returns the full path for all directories under "Data" (set a breakpoint after the `foreach` loop and examine the `merchants` array). The problem is in your table binding - it looks like you're binding to the `Length` property of each string somewhere.

Comment: @RufusL wpf code assigned .edit again .

Comment: What does your columns look like?

Comment: @Sach all of my tables get List<class> shema all works fine .but it doesn't

Comment: You have auto-generated columns, one for each property of the data item. Length is the only property of the string class.

Comment: No, I mean on your `DataGrid`. Either you need to specify columns, or you need to set `AutoGenerateColumns` property to `true`.

Comment: @Sach OP does already have auto-generated columns.

Comment: Use a ListBox instead of a DataGrid. And simplify your code to `merchantTable.ItemsSource =  Directory.GetDirectories(...)`

Comment: `merchantTable.ItemsSource = Directory.GetDirectories(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Data"));` would be a shorter way to write that code.

Comment: @Clemens ListBox worked !! can you post an answer ? why DataGrid not worked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A DataGrid is meant to show a set of columns, usually one for each property of the data item class, i.e. the element type of its `ItemsSource` collection.

Hence it doesn't make sense to use it for a collection of strings. Use a ListBox instead

```
<ListBox x:Name="merchantTable"/>
```

and simplify the ItemsSource assignment:

```
merchantTable.ItemsSource = Directory.GetDirectories(
     Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Data"));
```

---

If you really need to use a DataGrid, define a column like this:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="merchantTable" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Directory">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Your next solution also worked .Thank you very much .

Answer (score 0):

This code makes nearly no sense; you call a method that returns an array of string, that you then convert to a list, that you then add one by one to another list..

Anyhow, I think you then did something like set DisplayMemberPath or BindingPath to @Length and now your list control is showing you the lengths of all the strings in the list - do a debug print of merchants[0] and it will be a string that is 20 characters long. Data binding typically only binds to properties and a string only has one property. If you want to bind to the string itself you'll probably need to bind the column to a path of `.`

If you're wanting to show a list of folder names you'll need to call

```
merchants.Add(Path.GetFileName(i.TrimEnd(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar)));
```

When GetFilename is used on a path like `c:\temp\myfolder` it returns MyFolder

the Trim() is there because if you call GetFilename on `c:\temp\myfolder\` you get an empty string because it literally just returns everything after the last slash. (Which is nothing)

Comment: Yes, you've confirmed what I was thinking : your path is a string 20 characters long and you've bound to the length rather than the string. I think there isn't much else to recommend other than adjust your bindings?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28991304/how-to-display-a-list-of-strings-as-a-datagrid-table-in-xaml-and-c-sharp for example

Comment: I tested your code but it doesn't work with DataGrid

Comment: You set `Binding="{Binding Path=.}"` in your data grid column?

Comment: no i didn't is it necessary ? cuz i didn't set binding for other DataGrids

Comment: all of them works normally .show data and columns fine .

Comment: I meant what kinds of objects were the other grids showing? Probably not plain strings. Maybe instead of making a list of string you could make a new list of anonymous or dedicated type with a relevant property: `merchantTable.ItemsSource = Directory.GetDirectories(
     Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Data")).Select(x => new { Dirname: Path.GetFileName(x) }).ToList();` and rely on the default binding behavior